# How do I convert a 2D vector into 3D?

Tags: python

I have a 2D mathutils vector and I want to convert it to 3D, I know there is a method called **resize3D()** that does this, but it output an error "Vector Object doesn't have any attribute 'resize()'". I could manually construct a 3D vector from the components of this 2D one but is slower.

```
import mathutils

vector = mathutils.Vector((1,2))
vector.resize3D()
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want it to lay flat on the ground (z=0), you can simply add a 3rd value: `vector = mathutils.Vector((1,2,0))`

Comment: @TLousky The above example is just for demonstration, Blender gave me a 2d vector, I didn't create one, So I need to convert that 2D vector blender gave me to 3D where (z = 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDITED:

Did find a quicker, easier way after all:

```
v2d = Vector((1,2))
v3d = v2d.to_3d()
```

Or if you do prefer to do it in place, rather than assign to a new variable (you were very close in your original attempts):

```
v = Vector((1,2))
v.resize_3d()

>>> v
Vector((1.0, 2.0, 0.0)) # Has been converted in place to 3D
```

### Old method:

Generate a new 3D vector from your 2D one:

```
from mathutils import Vector
2dVec = Vector((1,2))

3dVec = Vector((2dVec.x, 2dVec.y, 0))
```

If you have a whole list of 2d vecs, you can simply use a list comprehension to convert 'em all:

```
3dVecs = [ Vector((2dVec.x, 2dVec.y, 0)) for 2dVec in 2dVecs ]
```

Comment: But as I stated, this method is slower. Will accept this as an answer if nobody provided a better way.

Comment: OK found a simpler solution, see revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, they should really update the documentation when they change the API.

Comment: Docs are up to date, perhaps you looked in an older version of the docs?
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector

Comment: Looks like it, why are those docs still up anyway?

Comment: Because people sometimes prefer to use older versions of Blender for compatibility issues (custom code, etc) - and they still need the correct documentation. It's always a good habit to check docs in the latest version if you're using it and just be aware of differences.